# What is the technique I should use now to go ahead?

Tags: sudoku

This is a partially filled sudoku from the Sudoku Expert app.

[image]

I thought I learnt all tricks and techniques. But clearly there is something I don't know about.

Comment: I got it from Sudoku Expert app.

Answer (score 2):

On the center rows, there are four squares which are either a 1 or a 5.

Now, what would happen if you put a

> 5 in row 8, column 2? That means row 5, column 8 is a 5 too, and row 6, column 9, a 1. Then there is no option for row 8, column 9. Therefore, the 5 in row 8 must be in column 9.

Schematic:

> [image]

Comment: You explanation seems incomplete. In row 8, column 2, you can put 1, 5 or 7 (1, 5 and 7 is also possible in row 7). 5 is not possible as explained. 1 would also not work work exactly the same reason. Thus, only 7 works there. Which give 1 in column 7 and finally 5 in column 9.

Comment: Wow. Why didn't I think of this before